# Can Steady Aim be used by a rogue aboard a moving ship?

Tags: dnd-5e, optional-rules

Can the Steady Aim optional class feature for rogues from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything be used when aboard a ship in motion, or other similar moving platform? What about a horse? The Steady Aim action includes the phrase "You can use this bonus action only if you haven't moved during this turn".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes.

Per Steady Aim,

> You can use this bonus action only if you haven't moved during this turn, and after you use the bonus action, your speed is 0 until the end of the current turn.

Per Movement and Position (PHB page 190),

> On your turn, you can move a distance up to your speed. You can use as much or as little of your speed as you like on your turn, following the rules here. Your movement can include jumping, climbing, and swimming. These different modes of movement can be combined with walking, or they can constitute your entire move. However you're moving, deduct the distance of each part of your move from your speed until it is used up or until you are done moving.

Per Opportunity Attack (PHB page 195),

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see moves out of your reach. ... You also don't provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or reaction. For example, you don't provoke an opportunity attack if an explosion hurls you out of a foe's reach or if gravity causes you to fall past an enemy.

Per Controlling a Mount (PHB page 198),

> The initiative of a controlled mount changes to match yours when you mount it. It moves as you direct it, and it has only three action options: Dash, Disengage, and Dodge. A controlled mount can move and act even on the turn that you mount it.

With all of this taken together, you move when you use up your speed. When you are on a mount or a vehicle, you are not using your speed; the vehicle or mount is moving you without using your movement (which some abilities and spell effects call "push"). If you are petrified, you "can't move", but that doesn't prevent you from being pushed around by outside forces.

Furthermore, if you are restrained (which sets your speed to 0) while mounted or aboard a vehicle, the mount or vehicle is not prevented from moving. Likewise, you "can't move" if you are petrified, but that doesn't prevent you from being pushed around by outside forces. So you could use the Steady Aim feature as a bonus action before the mount or vehicle moves you, use your action, then have the mount or vehicle move you, despite your speed being 0. I have made the case that the mount can move before you take the bonus action, and that still counts as "you haven't moved".